# Monaco Editor AddComment event fires twice

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I have configured the [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) to fire an event when `Ctrl+S` using [AddCommand](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#addcommand):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container" style="width:100%;height:700px;border:0px solid rgb(217, 219, 221);"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{! URLFOR($Resource.monaco,'vs/loader.js')}"></script>

    <script>

        var editor;

        window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {

            let message = event.data;

            // stuff happens here that I've removed....

            let language = 'javascript';
            let code = 'no code found...';
            let readOnly = false;

            createEditor(code, language, readOnly);
        }, false);

        function createEditor(_code, _language, _readOnly) {

            var container = document.getElementById('container')
            while (container.firstChild) {
                container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
            }

            require.config({ paths: { "vs": "{! URLFOR($Resource.monaco,'vs')}" } });
            require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {

                editor = monaco.editor.create(container, {
                    value: _code,
                    language: _language,
                    readOnly: _readOnly,
                });

                editor.addCommand(monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.KEY_S, function () {
                    let message = {};
                    message.action = 'save';
                    parent.postMessage(message, "*");
                    console.log('saved!!');
                })

                window.onresize = function () {
                    editor.layout();
                };
            });

        }

        createEditor('', 'apex');

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But the event fires twice.

The above code is run inside an iframe.

Note: the event does not execute if I press only one key, it only fires when I press both keys.

How can I stop the event from firing twice?

Comment: Does this also execute if you only press `CTRL`?

Comment: @NewToJS nope, the event does not execute if I press only one key

Comment: @Robs I followed this example https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/blob/master/browser-script-editor/index.html and added your code. Not able to reproduce it. Are you using any bundler?

Comment: ok that is a lot better, why do you need this " parent.postMessage(message, "*"); " ? Which is again going to create an editor on save and thereby bind the events againg

Comment: `parent.postMessage(message, "*")` tells the parent window to save the code... why is it going to cause the events to bind again?

Comment: parent is normally the window. unless your code is in iframe or you have done some kind of overriding. Your event listener on window will execute which is basically calling createeditor again and so the events will be binded again. If you put a console statement before monaco.editor.create, you will understand what I am saying

Comment: @karthick the code is inside an iframe

Comment: one last try, can you check if the window.parent propety actually points to the parent and not the iframe?console.log(window.parent === self, window.parent === window, window===self)

Comment: @karthick output `false false true`

Comment: A tough one if not able to reproduce, all I can say is add more console statements and go through your flow again. Make sure that window.addEventListener("message") ,  handles only the correct messages from trusted sources and executes only once.